# How do I complete a proof for an inequality by using the triangle inequality theorem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Prove that the inequality will hold for every real number, $x$

$$\left| 2+x \right| \le \left| 2x+1 \right| +\left| 1-x \right| $$

Proof: This proof is by case analysis.

Case 1:

1) Let $a=2x+1$ and let $b=1-x$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

2) Suppose $a+b \ge 0$, then $\left| a+b \right| =a+b$

3) Assume that $a\le \left| a \right|$ and $b\le \left| b \right| $, by adding these two inequalities, we get $a+b\le \left| a \right| +\left| b \right|$

4) Therefore we get that $\left| a+b \right| =a+b\le \left| a \right| +\left| b \right|$

Case 2:

1) Let $a=2x+1$ and let $b=1-x$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

2) Suppose $a+b < 0$, then $\left| a+b \right| = -a-b$

3) Assume that $-a\le \left| -a \right|$ and $-b\le \left| -b \right| $, by adding these two inequalities, we get $-a-b\le \left| a \right| +\left| b \right|$

4) Therefore we get that $\left| -a-b \right| =a+b\le \left| a \right| +\left| b \right|$

At this point, I have no idea what to do to complete my proof or to even show that my original claim is correct. I would like to be guided in the right direction. I am new to proof writing, so this is quite difficult for me to wrap my head around.

Comment: If I may suggest a much easier proof, note that $|2 + x| = |(2x + 1) + (1 - x)|$.

Comment: You don't need any other steps, after substituting $a = 2x+1$ and $b = 1 - x$ just use triangle inequality for $a, b$ as $|a+b| \le |a| + |b|$.

Comment: @Bungo My problem is that I notice those things, but I don't know how to turn something like that into a formal and complete proof.

Comment: @Kaster Can you please explain exactly what you mean? Preferably in an answer. I feel very lost with these proofs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a more elegant way to prove this inequality?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511576/is-there-a-more-elegant-way-to-prove-this-inequality)

Comment: @SimonS How is this a duplicate if I am asking for a proof verification here?

Comment: This is identical to your earlier question. You should ask follow up questions there in instead of creating a new post. That is the practice on Math SE.

Comment: The proof Kaster has is rigorous enough. You way of proofing is possible but definitely not the nicest way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a triangle inequality
$$
|a+b| \le |a| + |b|
$$
for every $a, b \in \mathbb R$. Now, just substitute $a = 2x+1$ and $b = 1-x$. Since triangle inequality is true for every $a,b$ it is true for those $a = 2x + 1$ and $b = 1-x$ as well. 
$$
a + b = 2x + 1 + 1 -x = 2+x \implies |a+b| = |x+2| \implies |x+2| \le |2x+1| + |1-x|
$$
And you're done.

Answer (score 0):

By the triangle inequality $|a| + |b| \ge |a + b|$

Let $a = 2x + 1$.  Let $b = 1 - x.$

Then $|2x + 1| + |1 - x| \ge |2x + 1 + 1 - x| = |x + 2|$